# Programmatically detecting if a folder is a cloud local folder

Tags: windows, cloud, directory, onedrive

Is there a way of detecting whether a particular folder is being used as the local store for cloud storage in Windows? The default name of the local cloud store folder seems to be the name of the Cloud provider (eg OneDrive, Google Drive, Dropbox) and local cloud folders are given distinctive icons. Folder and files within the local store also have additional icons indicating their sync status. However, users may rename local cloud store folders. Is there any folder attribute accessible from C# that will allow me to determine if a folder is a local cloud store?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you can use **storageFolder.Provider.Id**

documenting link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.provider?view=winrt-19041

exemple: `var provider = storageFolder.Provider;`

[1 - Exemple application in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fve2.png)

[2 - Exemple application in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLJlR.png)